# Apply a function to all keys of a Python dict

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to transform all the keys of a Python dict.

For example, if the keys are integers, I want to change each key to be the original value multiplied by 100.

What is the most performance-efficient way to achieve this?

The way I am doing it right now is by storing the original keys in a `set` and deleting those keys, replacing them by new keys - this had a problem that if I had a `key=2` and a `key=200` in the original key set, there would be collision, which I would have to handle recursively until I find a key with no collision with the original key-set.

Answer (score 17):

You can use a dict comprehension:

```
>>> d = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
>>> {k*100: v for k, v in d.items()}
{200: 'b', 300: 'c', 100: 'a'}
```

Replace `items()` with `iteritems()` if you're using Python 2.

Answer (score 5):

I would use [Dictionary Comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) for this.

```
result = {your_func(key): value for key, value in your_dict.iteritems()}
```

Comment: In Python 3, you can just use `your_dict.items()`

Answer (score 1):

To add a dict comprehension answer that will work identically in Python 2.7 and Python 3.x:

```
{ your_func(key): your_dict[key] for key in your_dict }
```

It's even a little faster then `items/iteritems` (at least on my trivial test; profile your code to be sure).

```
# Python 2
>>> timeit.timeit( '{2*x: y for x,y in d.iteritems()}', 'd={1:2, 2:4}')
0.4100990295410156
>>> timeit.timeit( '{2*x: d[x] for x in d}', 'd={1:2, 2:4}')
0.38503098487854004

# Python 3
>>> timeit.timeit( '{2*x: y for x,y in d.items()}', 'd={1:2, 2:4}')
0.5370963809546083
>>> timeit.timeit( '{2*x: d[x] for x in d}', 'd={1:2, 2:4}')
0.4837625279906206
```

Comment: Great alternative if compatibility is an issue: the performance gain is trivial, though, so in the spirit of "explicit > implicit" I would go with `(iter)items()` if  I only need to support one version

Comment: this is because of two reasons. 1 - your test dict is too small, 2 - your test dict keys are ints, try to generate a long dict and measure it once again

Comment: @Alex Can you back that up? I'm actually interested--I would have though *a priori* that `items()` is faster too

Comment: @brianpck 1 - there is no hash collision on a small dict, 2 - because calculation hash for int is faster than for str(this is something I'm not 100% sure but it should be like this). There might be even more reasons but I'm not that deep in python source codes.

Comment: I suspect the speed-up is due solely to avoiding one extra call to `items()`; in both cases, you are traversing an iterator, so the ratio should approach 1 as the size of the `dict` increases. My comment that it is faster was somewhat tongue-in-cheek.